# How to flatten along 3rd dimension in numpy?

Tags: numpy

I have a 3d array in numpy that I want to flatten into a 1d array. I want to flatten each 2d "layer" of the array, copying each successive layer into the 1d array.

e.g., for an array with `arr[:, :, 0] = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]` and `arr[:, :, 1] = [[5, 6], [7, 8]]`, I want the output to be `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`.

Currently I have the following code:

```
out = np.empty(arr.size)
for c in xrange(arr.shape[2]):
    layer = arr[:, :, c]
    out[c * layer.size:(c + 1) * layer.size] = layer.ravel()
```

Is there a way to accomplish this efficiently in numpy (without using a `for` loop)? I have tried messing around with `reshape`, `transpose`, and `flatten` to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or (the last axe will be first) : `np.rollaxis(a,-1).ravel()`

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out:

`out = arr.transpose((2, 0, 1)).flatten()`